# stay on current month

Tags: fullcalendar

When I am in the month view of FullCalendar, then say I go back a few months to March and click on an event, then hit the browser 'back' button, how can I make it so that the browser knows to go back to March?  Currently, it just goes back to the current month.

Thanks

Comment: When you click on the Next/Prev button of fullCalendar it loads the month on fly (it doesn't re-load the page). That's why for browser, you are still on the same page. Hence the back button of the browser will never know how to take you to the desired month. Instead it will blindly take you to the previously visited URL.

Comment: well, my montly calendar events are clickable...so that when I click on one it takes me to another page.  And when I click the back button...it takes me to todays month and not whatever month I happened to be on.

Comment: In eventClick callback, are you redirecting the user to some other page?

Comment: What your talking about is using hash tags... But you will have to dig through the fullcalendar.js script and find out where to put them and then write another script to remember what and where the pages are. There are really nice plugins to do the latter part of this, (one specifically is called jquery bbq at http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ ) but you will still have to modify the original js yourself. Other than this approach, I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

From **eventClick** callback, when you redirect the user to the other page. Also send current day, month and year of the calendar in the URL.
On that page get the values from URL and store them in session variables.

This is how you can get current date of the fullCalendar:

```
var calCurrDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
var date = calCurrDate.getDate();
var month = calCurrDate.getMonth();
var year = calCurrDate.getFullYear();
```

Now on calendar page check if those session variables are defined. If they are defined, add the following properties to fullCalendar

```
<cfif isDefined('SESSION.d')>
    <cfoutput>
        date: #SESSION.d#,
        month: #SESSION.m#,
        year: #SESSION.y#,
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

For server side language I've used Coldfusion (as I know only this). You can easily understand the logic and translate it to your desired language.

Note: At the end of the calendar page you must destroy the session variables. Otherwise every time when you refresh the page you'll be taken to the same day, month and year.

I hope this helps. Thanks